# maliit virtual keyboard bring up

Tags: qt, virtual-keyboard, imx6

I'm trying to integrate maliit virtual keyboard into an embedded board.

environmental details:

- qt4 with X11
- imx6 board.
- maliit framework version **0.81**
- maliit plugin version **0.80**

cross-compilation details:

1. maliit framework

   ```
   qmake M_IM_PREFIX=/home/root/maliit/usr M_IM_DEFAULT_PLUGIN=libmaliit-keyboard-plugin.so  CONFIG+=disable-gtk-cache-update  CONFIG+=notests -r
   make 
   sudo make install
   ```
2. maliit plugin

   ```
   qmake M_IM_PREFIX=/home/root/maliit/usr -r
   make 
   sudo make install
   ```

I copied the output folder to the embedded board and tried to start the virtual keyboard

```
 export QT_PLUGIN_PATH=/home/root/maliit/usr/lib/maliit/plugin-0.80
 export QT_IM_MODULE=Maliit
 maliit-server &
```

and started maliit test application

```
maliit-exampleapp-plainqt
```

but the keyboard is not coming when I touch the text field.

am I missing anything here?